# Scala cats, how to make this Validated code compile?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I am learning validated data types of the cats library lately.

How to make this code compile?

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data._
import cats.data.Validated._


sealed trait Expression {
  type ValidationResult[A] = ValidatedNel[String, A]
  def eval: ValidationResult[Double] = {
    this match {
      case Addition(left: Expression, right: Expression) =>
        (left.eval: ValidationResult[Double], right.eval: ValidationResult[Double]).mapN(_ + _)
      case Number(value) => value.validNel
      case Division(left, right) => right match {
        case Number(0) => "Divide by zero".invalidNel
        case _ => (left.eval, right.eval).mapN(_ / _)
      }
    }
  }
}

final case class Addition(left: Expression, right: Expression) extends Expression
final case class Division(left: Expression, right: Expression) extends Expression
final case class Number(value: Double) extends Expression

val l = Division(Number(5), Number(0))
val r = Division(Number(10), Number(0))
println(Addition(l, r).eval)
```

No matter what I tried, it just keeps complaining

```
value mapN is not a member of (Expression.this.ValidationResult[Double], Expression.this.ValidationResult[Double])
(left.eval: ValidationResult[Double], right.eval: ValidationResult[Double]).mapN(_ + _)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it was caused by an ambiguous implicit? Or an old version? It may also be just a bug in the IDE since [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/sFhHAsN5QH2uvWbSwKkdGw/1) seems to work. - PS: You may want to rather use the new parallel syntax with `Either` and use `NonEmptyChain` instead of `NEL

Comment: Hi Luis, I'm using Intelij Idea with scala plugin. Will VS Code + metal fix this bug?

Comment: well you should always compile using **sbt** or any other build tool jus to confirm, specially when using **IntelliJ**. While using **vscode** + **metals** would indeed be more reliable since it talks to a real compiler _(and I actually use and prefer that one)_ it lacks more features.

Comment: can you provide scala version and cats version?

Comment: @BorisAzanov My scala version is 2.12.10, cats version is cats-core_2.12 with 2.16. I'm using maven as build tool and Intellij IDEA 2021.2.3

Comment: Can you provide `pom.xml` file? I can't reproduce your problem even using maven and idea + scala plugin.

Comment: Sorry @BorisAzanov, I misremembered. I'm using gradle, my sbt is """name := "scalawithcats"
version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.1.0"

// scalac options come from the sbt-tpolecat plugin so need to set any here
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Xfatal-warnings"
)
addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.11.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
"""

Comment: Unfortunately couldn't still reproduce your problem even in scastie https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bCaGUIhDS7CyjZNDEMpbLg , I can just advise to close project in IDEA, remove `.idea` directory from sources root and reimport this project into IDEA.

Comment: @BorisAzanov finally it works by deleting ```.idea``` dir and reimport! Thx buddy